# How is java `wait()` waiting implemented?

Tags: java

I'm asking about the waiting process not the access ordering method is it in the simplest form an infinite loop with a conditional exit.

Whats the least resource consuming way to wait for a request thats what got me to ask this.

Answer (score 13):

[`Object.wait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) functionality is implemented with `JVM_MonitorWait` native method, as per `ThreadReference` javadoc:

```
/** Thread is waiting - Object.wait() or JVM_MonitorWait() was called */
public final int THREAD_STATUS_WAIT = 4;
```

The implementation of this method can be found in [`jvm.cpp`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/80abf702eed8/src/hotspot/share/prims/jvm.cpp#l602) and uses `ObjectSynchronizer::wait`:

```
JVM_ENTRY(void, JVM_MonitorWait(JNIEnv* env, jobject handle, jlong ms))
  JVMWrapper("JVM_MonitorWait");
  Handle obj(THREAD, JNIHandles::resolve_non_null(handle));
  JavaThreadInObjectWaitState jtiows(thread, ms != 0);
  if (JvmtiExport::should_post_monitor_wait()) {
    JvmtiExport::post_monitor_wait((JavaThread *)THREAD, (oop)obj(), ms);

    // The current thread already owns the monitor and it has not yet
    // been added to the wait queue so the current thread cannot be
    // made the successor. This means that the JVMTI_EVENT_MONITOR_WAIT
    // event handler cannot accidentally consume an unpark() meant for
    // the ParkEvent associated with this ObjectMonitor.
  }
  ObjectSynchronizer::wait(obj, ms, CHECK);
JVM_END
```

`ObjectSynchronizer::wait` implementation is in [`synchronizer.cpp`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/caf115bb98ad/src/hotspot/share/runtime/synchronizer.cpp#l479) and delegates to `ObjectMonitor::wait` in [`objectMonitor.cpp`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/83aec1d357d4/src/hotspot/share/runtime/objectMonitor.cpp#l1416).

If you continue to dig in you will eventually reach the native Java thread implementation which is platform dependent. On Linux this will be `libpthread.so` which will ultimately handle the thread status change.

Answer (score 4):

> is it in the simplest form an infinite loop with a conditional exit?

No it isn't.  That is inefficient, and not how it is typically done.

The details are complicated and system dependent (see @Karol's answer for links to the code), but the general approach is as follows.

When the thread calls `wait()`, the method does the following:

1. Add the thread details to the mutex object's queue of "objects waiting".
2. Relinquish the thread's mutex lock.
3. "Park" the thread by telling the OS to put it to sleep.
4. The OS finds some other thread to schedule.  If there is none, it causes the core to go into a low power "idle" loop or suspends it or something.  (This is OS and hardware dependent.)

Then when another thread calls `notify`, the notify method does the following:

1. It removes a thread from the mutex queue.
2. It tells the OS that the (previously) waiting thread should be woken.
3. It returns from the `notify()` call and (hopefully) releases the mutex lock.

The OS does the following:

1. It finds a free processor to run the thread, and starts.
2. If no core is free, the OS adds the thread to the scheduler's queue of runnable threads.
3. When the thread starts, it first tries to reacquire the mutex lock ... which may cause it to be put back to sleep, if some other thread is still holding the lock.
4. Finally the `wait` call returns, and the thread will typically recheck the condition variable, and then release the lock.

The point is that there are (typically) no infinite loops that that consume CPU while a thread is waiting.

---

> Whats the least resource consuming way to wait for a request that is what got me to ask this.

The least resource consuming way would be `Object.wait` and `Object.notify` ...

Answer (score 0):

In synchronous programing, a monitor can be assumed like a box or more specifically a control box (to make any changes in an object) with a space of only one thread at any given instant. So, multiple threads can be prevented from writing one object at the same time and protecting the object from getting corrupted. In it, wait() method tells a thread, if any other thread is already sitting in the monitor and if so, tells the calling thread to WAIT for the other thread to come out. Or technically, tells the calling thread to SLEEP until notified.

It stops any further execution of code in the calling thread, unlike a infinite loop, in which the execution continues, but no code after the loop is executed until the loop breaks.

Comment: i hope it helped :)